# Mediawiki - only a certain user group can read / access

Tags: permissions, mediawiki

I'm setting up a wiki at the moment and I want it to be completely private and only be accessible for a specific user group.

My first step was:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']    = false;
```

that way no one (but admins I guess) should be able to read any content of the Wiki.

After that I created some groups to allow read only, read edit and creating allowance etc.

Sadly I tried to register a new test account and I could still read the main wiki page even though I changed the permission that no one should be able to read it except the user groups I created.

Do I miss something?

Comment: How about just requiring users to log in to the server? Restricted access is [not really what MediaWiki was built for](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Security_issues_with_authorization_extensions).

Comment: Did you manage this? I'd like to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = false;` as `*` still allows visitors in the `users` group to read.

Answer (score 0):

That method specifically allows Users that have created accounts to view the wiki.  See this manual page: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_all_pages, it's the second Warning.  So you may want to also restrict account creation.